# Are $d(f,g)=\max \limits_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|$ or $d(f,g)=\min \limits_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|$ metric?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Neither $d(f,g)=\max \limits_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|$ nor $d(f,g)=\min \limits_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|$ meet the triangle equality condition to be metric. Because if you some $x$ (say $x_1$) such that $|f(x) - g(x)|$ is minimum (maximum) it doesn't mean that there is some $x_2$ that both of $|f(x_1) - h(x_2)|$  and $|h(x_2) - g(x_2)|$ are minimum (maximum), i.e. maybe for $x_3\ne x_1$, $|f(x_3) - h(x_2)|$ and for $x_4\ne x_1$, $|h(x_2) - g(x_4)|$ is minimum (maximum); and even may $x_2$ changes when $x_3$ or $x_4$ comes along?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g,h$ be functions. For the max case,
$$
\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left|f-g\right|=\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left|f-h+h-g\right|\leq\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left(\left|f-h\right|+\left|h-g\right|\right)\leq\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left|f-h\right|+\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left|h-g\right|
$$

That is, the triangle inequality holds.

---

For the min case, let $a=-1$ and $b=1$ and consider the
functions $f=1$ and $g=-1$. Then,
$$
\min_{a\leq x\leq b}|f(x)-g(x)|=|1-(-1)|=2.
$$
However,
$$
\min_{a\leq x\leq b}|f(x)-x|=\min_{a\leq x\leq b}|x-g(x)|=0.
$$
That is, the triangle inequality does not hold.

Comment: And exactly my problem is: why $\left\Vert f-h+h-g\right\Vert _{\infty}\leq\left\Vert f-h\right\Vert _{\infty}+\left\Vert h-g\right\Vert _{\infty}$?

Comment: Triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$; see above edit.

Comment: Sorry, I went all the way but the last inequality! Would you please tell me how to drive $\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left(\left|f-h\right|+\left|h-g\right|\right)\leq\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left|f-h\right|+\max_{a\leq x\leq b}\left|h-g\right|$ ? Thank you

Comment: Try to derive the proof of this claim from intuition: is the maximum of $\max a(x)+b(x)$ smaller (with possible equality) or larger than $\max a(x)+\max b(x)$? Draw a picture if necessary.

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444977/prove-df-g-min-fx-gx-in-ca-b-is-not-metric