# Prove $d(f,g)= \min {|f(x)-g(x)}|$ in $C[a,b]$ is not metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Trying to answer whether we can set in the set of real continuous functions in the closed interval $[a,b]$ metric $d(f,g)$
I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698644/are-df-g-max-limits-a-leq-x-leq-b-fx-gx-or-df-g-min-limits)

> For the min case, let $a=−1$ and $b=1$ and consider the functions $f=1$ and > $g=−1$. Then, $\min_ {a≤x≤b}|f(x)−g(x)|=|1−(−1)|=2$. However,$\min _{a≤x≤b}|f(x)−x|=\min_{a≤x≤b}|x−g(x)|=0$. That is, the triangle inequality > does not hold.

I don't understand why is works. We just measured the distance between $f(x)$ and $x$, $g(x)$ and $x$ and gave the conclusion that the triangle inequality does not satisfy. *We could have use the same points to prove* $d_1(f,g)= \max{|f(x)-g(x)|}$ is not metric, which obiusly does satisfy the inequality.

**Why is  $d(f,g)= \min {|f(x)-g(x)|}$ not metric in $C[a,b]$?**

Comment: $d$ is not a metric because the triangle equality does not hold, as demonstrated in the quoted Q&A. $d_1$ is a metric, and the same argument does *not* work for $d_1$.

Comment: Also, you could have $d(f,g) = 0$ if $f, g$ 'cross', but that does not mean that they are equal everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Consider, $f,g,h \in C[a,b]$ with $f-g$ having a zero, $g-h$ having a zero but $f-h$ does not have a zero, then the triangle inequality is violated. For example $a=0$, $b=\frac{1}{b}(x-a), c=1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is another issue to check: $d(f,g)=0 $ $\iff$ $f=g$. Put $f=x-a, g=0$ then....

Comment: It does satistfy the first axiom

Comment: In order to be a metric,  it should satisfy all the axioms not just one...

Comment: I know, I am asking for the last axiom. Why does it not satisfy it ?

Comment: Define please the last axiom,  so I can check it...

Comment: It must satisfy the triangle inequality.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)